# Lex "Error: Action does not terminate" error

Tags: lex

I am creating a .lex file for an independent study. I am running into a lex error as stated in the title of this question. It is happening on line 119, (the lines are numbered). I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong? I did not include the token.h file but if it is needed I will post it. My .lex file is named scanner.lex and is as follows:

```
  1 %{
  2 #include <string.h>
  3 #include "token.h"
  4 
  5 int current_line_number = 1;
  6 
  7 void newLine() {
  8      current_line_number++;
  9 }
  10 
  11 int yywrap(void) {
  12      return 1;
  13 }
  14 
  15 %}
  16 
  17 %%
  18 " "                             { }
  19 \n                              {newLine();}
  20 and                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  21                                  return AND;}
  22 array                           {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  23                                  return ARRAY;}
  24 begin                           {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  25                                  return BEGIN;}
  26 boolean                         {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  27                                  return BOOLEAN;}
  28 div                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  29                                  return DIV;}
  30 do                              {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  31                                  return DO;}
  32 else                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  33                                  return ELSE;}
  34 end                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  35                                  return END;}
  36 false                           {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  37                                  return FALSE;}
  38 for                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  39                                  return FOR;}
  40 goto                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  41                                  return GOTO;}
  42 if                              {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  43                                  return IF;]
  44 imply                           {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  45                                  return IMPLY;}
  46 integer                         {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  47                                  return INTEGER;}
  48 label                           {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  49                                  return LABEL;}
  50 not                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  51                                  return NOT;}
  52 or                              {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  53                                  return OR;}
  54 own                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  55                                  return OWN;}
  56 procedure                       {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  57                                  return PROCEDURE;}
  58 real                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  59                                  return REAL;}
  60 step                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  61                                  return STEP;}
  62 string                          {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  63                                  return STRING;}
  64 then                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  65                                  return THEN;}
  66 true                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  67                                  return TRUE;}
  68 until                           {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  69                                  return UNTIL;}
  70 value                           {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  71                                  return VALUE;}
  72 while                           {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  73                                  return WHILE;}
  74 [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*            {yylval.string_value.line_number = current_line_number;
  75                                  yylval.string_value.value = malloc(sizeof(char) *(strlen    (yytext)+1));
  76                                  return IDENTIFIER;}
  77 [0-9]+                          {yylval.integer_value.line_number = current_line_number;
  78                                  yylval.integer_value.value = atoi(yytext);
  79                                  return INT;}
  80 [0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*        {yylval.real_value.line_number = current_line_number;
  81                                  yylval.real_value.value = atof(yytext);
  82                                  return REAL;}
  83 "+"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  84                                  return PLUS;}
  85 "-"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  86                                  return MINUS;}
  87 "*"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  88                                  return MULT;}
  89 "/"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  90                                  return DIV;}
  91 "<"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  92                                  return LESS;}
  93 "<="                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  94                                  return LESSEQ;}
  95 ">"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  96                                  return GREAT;}
  97 ">="                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  98                                  return GREATEQ;}
  99 "="                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  100                                  return EQ;}
  101 "!="                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  102                                  return NOTEQ;}
  103 ","                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  104                                  return COMMA;}
  105 ":"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  106                                  return COLON;}
  107 ";"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  108                                  return SEMI;}
  109 "("                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  110                                  return LPARAN;}
  111 ")"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  112                                  return RPARAN;}
  113 "["                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  114                                  return LBRAK;}
  115 "]"                             {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  116                                  return RBRAK;}
  117 ":="                            {yylval.line_number = current_line_number;
  118                                  return ASSIGN;}
  119 .                               {printf("Found other data \"%s\"\n", yytext);
  120                                  return 1;}
  121                                 
  122 %%
```

Here is the actual error message:

```
cs368@admiral:~/cs4880$ lex scanner.lex
"scanner.lex":line 119: Error: Action does not terminate
```

Also, I would appreciate it something else does not seem right, suggestions are welcomed. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. On line 43 I had typed a "]" instead of "}" Still if you see anything that can be improved, I would appreciate it.